# Bring the app to front if it is already running rather than creating new instance of it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching system apps from my app and I can successfully launch it using this code

```
Intent i=getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("Your package name");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAGS_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAGS_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

But it always restarted or created new instance of app.If the particular app is already running I want it to bring it to front rather than creating new instance of it..
I have tried many methods but didn't worked it always created new instance on the top of my running app.
Please anyone solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the launch mode of the activity you want to start.

If the launch mode is "standard" it is not possible to bring it to the front:

> a new instance is **always** created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard" [(source)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

For all other launch modes, try using the following two flags:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) this should have the following effect (which should match your desired behavior):

> `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is most often used in conjunction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. When used together, these flags are a way of locating an existing activity in another task and putting it in a position where it can respond to the intent.

Comment: OK I will try this:)

Comment: No it doesn't worked it still create new instance on the above of my launched app:(